# Why some code on Samsung Galaxy S does not work?

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-tabhost, android

I am writing an application for Android devices.

After finishing the development and testing the program, I find that the following NullPointerException is thrown only on the Samsung Galaxy S. The application does not have this problem on other Android devices.

The error message captured in logcat is,

```
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:298)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:302)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:302)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:662)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1921)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
05-06 09:09:15.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10657):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It has not pointed out which line in my source code causes the problem. I checked the TabHost object and it is not null.

Could anyone give me some idea to solve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this happen on application startup or does something you do in the application trigger it? Even if you can't see your code with a line number in logcat, you should be able to attach the debugger and figure out see roughly what you're doing when this error occurs.

Comment: This issue triggered after I click the tab. And a interesting thing is there have five tab in this tab host, and I click three of them is ok, only two tab have trggier this error....

Comment: Good, getting closer. What's different about the two tabs that crash as compared to the three that don't? Also, posting code would allow us to more closely see what's going on.

Comment: A good news, I get back the previous version and run on galaxy s, it works.
The different between this two version is I add a TabHost into a ViewFlipper.
Dose it has any wrong syntax in the layout XML??

Because the currently layout tree in my program at this part is,

TabHost > ViewFiler > TabHost

Comment: Please post the contents of the XML layout file in question - it's difficult to identify syntax errors without seeing the code.

Comment: Oh, I found out what is the problem. It is because I added a TabHost into ViewFlipper. After I remove the TabHost which is inside the ViewFlipper, the NullPointerException is disappear.
Maybe I post the XML later.
Thank you very much, Jordan.